# CYGWIN Ms-Dos path detected warning

Tags: c, windows, unix, cygwin

I am using Windows, i have a c file on my desktop. It includes unix code. When i write "*gcc -o MyExe C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ccode.c*" on cygwin terminal, it gives a warning like "MS-DOS path detected". How should i write it?

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin remaps Windows-style paths to a UNIX-compatible format, using `/` rather than `\` as a directory separator (though Windows also accepts `/`), and putting all the drive letters into a virtual directory called `/cygdrive`.

Change this:

```
gcc -o MyExe C:/Users/Username/Desktop/ccode.c
```

to this:

```
gcc -o MyExe /cygdrive/C/Users/Username/Desktop/ccode.c
```

---

Cygwin also gives you a UNIX-style home directory. For a typical Cygwin installation, that directory will be at `C:\cygwin\home\username` as seen from Windows, or at `/home/username` as seen from Cygwin (also visible at `/cygdrive/cygwin/C/home/username`). As on actual UNIX/Linux systems, you can refer to your home directory as `$HOME` or `~` in many contexts. It's usually distinct from your Windows home directory `C:\Users\username`. I usually ignore the Windows home directory and just use my Cygwin home directory. But if you prefer you can certainly use your Windows home directory from Cygwin; it will just be a little harder to refer to it (and some file have to be in your Cygwin home directory.)

It *might* be possible to configure Cygwin to use your Windows home directory as your Cygwin home directory; I haven't tried it myself, and it might cause problems.

Comment: i tried that but i got a " No such file or directory" error

Comment: @TamerMemili: Hmm. I think Windows does some funny stuff with special directories like `Desktop`. If you open a Windows command prompt, can you see the file at `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ccode.c`?

Comment: i just see your comment about unix style home directory. İ copied my c file to that directory and i tried to access it as unix style, like gcc -o Myexe /home/username/ccode.c but still the same error, no such file or directory. İ dont install all the features of cygwin, only the ones about gcc. İs this a problem?

Comment: @TamerMemili: From a Windows command prompt, do you see the file at `C:\cygwin\home\username\ccode.c`?

Comment: i tried it now, no i cant see that file, what should i do?

Comment: @TamerMemili: You said you copied the file to that directory. Apparently you didn't. I don't know what you did to try to copy it, so I can't tell you why it didn't work.

Comment: @TamerMemili: Try creating a file in that directory.